# Find the equation for the isoline given

Tags: linear-algebra

I don't really understand the question, it's probably really simple but I don't really get it right know

> A linear function   of two variables has the equation 
>   $f(x,y)=10x+20y$
>   a)    Find the equation for the isoline given by
>   $f(x,y)=80$

[image: graph]

Answer (score 1):

Just draw
$$
f(x,y) = 80 \iff \\
10 x + 20 y = 80 \iff \\
y = - \frac{1}{2} x + 4
$$
That line goes through $(0,4)$ and $(8,0)$.

Comment: Ahhhhhh get it now! Thanks a lot!!!!